why is my weback server not reloading live?
I have just installed a Webpack server which also works. But it annoys me that I always have to reload the browser. So I tried to improve this with hot;true. It still does not work. This is a plain Javascript project
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js", // Einstiegspunkt im src-Ordner
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js", // Name der gebündelten Datei
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"), // Ausgabeordner
    publicPath: "/",
  },
  devServer: {
    static: path.join(__dirname, "src"), // Ordner, in dem sich die HTML-Datei befindet
    port: 9000, // Port, auf dem der Server läuft
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
  },
  mode: "development", // Entwicklungsmodus
  target: "web", // Zielumgebung Web
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/, // Regex für JavaScript-Dateien
        exclude: /node_modules/, // Schließt node_modules aus
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader", // Verwendet Babel zum Transpilieren
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"], // Verwendet das preset-env Preset
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};


I only set Hot to true but honestly have no idea what I need to do for Live reload

To enable live reloading, Webpack needs to know which files have changed.
Using the devServer.watchFiles option you can define paths to your source files.
Add the watchFiles option into devServer:
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js", // Einstiegspunkt im src-Ordner
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js", // Name der gebündelten Datei
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"), // Ausgabeordner
    publicPath: "/",
  },
  devServer: {
    static: path.join(__dirname, "src"), // Ordner, in dem sich die HTML-Datei befindet
    port: 9000, // Port, auf dem der Server läuft
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,

    // live reload after changes the files defined in watchFiles.paths
    watchFiles: {
      paths: ['src/**/*.*'], // watch changes
      options: {
        usePolling: true,
      },
    },
  },
  mode: "development", // Entwicklungsmodus
  target: "web", // Zielumgebung Web
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/, // Regex für JavaScript-Dateien
        exclude: /node_modules/, // Schließt node_modules aus
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader", // Verwendet Babel zum Transpilieren
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"], // Verwendet das preset-env Preset
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};

